# Do java classes metadata go on the heap?

Tags: java, class, heap-memory

In Java when classloader loads class files, where do the loaded clases reside? In the heap? I understand that objects lie in the heap but what about the class itself? In Java even Class is an Object, so my guess is that it goes on the heap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information associated with a loaded class (methods, fields, etc.) reside in the [method area](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4).

> Although the method area is logically part of the heap, simple
>   implementations may choose not to either garbage collect or compact
>   it. This version of the Java Virtual Machine specification does not
>   mandate the location of the method area or the policies used to manage
>   compiled code.

The method area may or may not be a part of the heap, it is entirely up to the JVM implementation to decide where to store it.

`Class` objects themselves will be stored on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

From the Java 8 release, 'class metadata' is stored in the metaspace region. The beauty of the MetaSpace region is it grows automatically when in need and we can set its upper bound as well by setting maxMetaSpaceSize.

Before Java 8 release, it used to be a part of the PermGen region. And PermGen was a part of the heap so in that sense yes, to your question.

[PermGen vs Metaspace](https://www.baeldung.com/java-permgen-metaspace)